# Why MetaMask always asking high gas price? which one can i use alternative to metamask for token distribution?

Tags: solidity, mist, remix, metamask, airdrop

While i am distributing tokens i am using a special contract to airdrop the               tokens to multiple addresses at a time but metamask is demanding high gas prices which costs me huge am always checking in ethgasstation.info there safe low gas price showing 2 and at the same time metamask is demanding 8 gas price why is this much?

can anyone suggest me alternative to metamask to perform airdrop with safe low gas price.

please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can just change the gas price in MetaMask when it asks you to approve the transaction.

Comment: yes i can change but its not taking the transaction till i put its demanding gas price like if safe gas low in ethgasstatio.info is 2 gas price if i try to enter that 2 gas in metamask its not taking that gas price and if i randomly change gas price to put its taking 4x times greater that that safe gas low value  :(

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand what you're saying. What exactly goes wrong when you try to use a lower gas price?

Comment: https://ibb.co/kguJvR   see in the image   if i put 4x more that safe low gas then its taking and the transaction is processing successfully.

Comment: What gas price did you use? https://www.ethgasstation.info/ currently has a 6 gwei "SafeLow" price. I believe the error message you're getting is probably coming from Infura (the node MetaMask connects to by default). If you're planning to switch to a different tool, you may need to find one that doesn't use Infura.

Comment: can u suggest me which tool doesnt use infura?

Comment: You could run your own node and use Mist or geth. Or you could sign transactions offline and broadcast them via etherscan.io (or anywhere, really). Other than those options, no, I don't happen to know of such a tool. If you find a node you like, you could continue to use MetaMask and just point it at that node.

Answer (score 0):

If metamask warn you that the gas amount is abnormaly high then it's maybe related to your contract function!

In my case, it's an exchange between ETH and token so it may imply the call I'm trying to do may miss ETH or token in one side of the order/user balance,order canceled, anything that would not make the transaction succesfull.

Im not enought expert to say how to debug or return!